# Is URL percent-encoding case sensitive?

Tags: url, urlencode, url-encoding, percent-encoding

Is `%3B` treated differently to `%3b` in an URL?

Comment: I found some conflicting information. I thought asking a question would be the easiest way to clear things up.

Comment: Ok. I believe the information in the link says that it's from the RFC. But how it's implemented is always a mystery with browser manufacturers. ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**No**,  URL percent-encoding is NOT case sensitive. According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1):

> **2.1. Percent-Encoding**
>
> [...]
>
> The uppercase hexadecimal digits 'A' through 'F' are equivalent to the
> lowercase digits 'a' through 'f', respectively.  If two URIs differ
> only in the case of hexadecimal digits used in percent-encoded octets,
> they are equivalent.

Comment: It may be appropriate to mention that in cases where a URI is used for a namespace declaration in XML (also XHTML, SOAP etc), that percent-encoding has no effect (it is not decoded) and simply part of the string that makes up the namespace. As a result, it *is* case-sensitive. I.e. `xmlns:t="http://foo.bar/%2A"` is *not equal, nor equivalent* to `xmlns:t="http://foo.bar/%2a"`.

Comment: @Abel while true, that's really down to XML namespaces not really being URIs (although their specification falsely claims otherwise). For example, the part of the namespace which purports to be a domain component is also case-sensitive in XML namespace declarations, in violation of RFC 3986.

Comment: exactly, that was the point here, thanks for giving more context